# Zxing Causing Android App to Force Close

Tags: android, zxing

Whenever the activity that initiates the scan happens, the android application force closes. It worked at one point and suddenly won't work anymore. Core.jar is in a lib folder.

Logcat:

```
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.picky.pickyeater/libcom.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: libcom.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.picky.pickyeater-1.apk]
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: libcom.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.picky.pickyeater-1.apk]
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-08 18:13:16.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

OnCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml excerpt:

```
<activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

.classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/gson-1.7.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jsoup-1.6.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/core.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Have you renamed the package?

Comment: It's not a package - it's a jar on the build path

Comment: Seems like the jar is not present in the build path. You need to add the core.jar to your project (Right-click your project –> Properties –> Java Build Path –> Add External JARS… –> Select core.jar –> OK).

Comment: Yeah it's definitely in there. I've tried taking it out and reimporting it, but no-go

Comment: Could you please post the content of your .classpath file? Is your lib folder in your project's root folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know that according to Sean above, this is technically incorrect, but this was solved by linking it in as a library.

 
**In ZXing:**  
1. Right click on project 
2. Click **Properties** 
3. Click **Android** in the left hand side menu 
4. Check **Is Library**

**In my app:** 
1. Right click on project 
2. Click **Properties** 
3. Click **Android** in the left hand side menu 
4. Click **Add** 
5. Select the ZXing project

Comment: Do *not* use the code in android/ like a library. It isn't a library and doesn't work that way. We strongly discourage copy and paste of the whole app. In particular we think using it this way violates trademark. Don't encourage this even if its not what you are doing in the end.

Comment: It was a class project. We never went anywhere with it. I sincerely apologize.

Answer (score 5):

zxing is not doing anything here. You copied and pasted our code, and have not included it in your JAR. You are simply seeing a `ClassNotFoundException`; you're not even getting to the point where you use our code.

FWIW we strongly discourage this level of copy-and-paste of our open source code. Please write your own application to start, and reuse pieces that you need. From the error, it seems this is not what you are going.

More strongly, you should not be using our package name.

Comment: Wait I'm confused. I really didn't mean to copy anything. We just followed the directions for including the jar. How do you suggest we correctly access the scanning?

Our package name is com.picky.pickyeater

Comment: Something in your layout is referencing 'libcom.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity' and that is the root of the problem. I am not sure what instructions you are following, but you shouldn't need to include anything except `core.jar` not anything from `android/`

Comment: There isn't anything in our project from android/. Is how we're referencing it the section in our Manifest incorrect? Or the reference to SCAN in the OnCreate()?

Comment: I don't know your app, so I couldn't tell you. I can see a reference to our package from `android/`. You must have copied something. I imagine that's your problem then, that you're using bits of our code when you don't know it or realize it and it's causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help - you were right. My teammates included it as a library instead of a jar, and I included the jar not realizing that's not how they did it.

Comment: @SeanOwen Owen Can you give us some info? Like, What algorithm you used to write this Zxing?

Answer (score 2):

To my experience, I met the same problem. But if you are using eclipse, please make sure that you have **REALLY** included the library(CaptureActivity) in your own project.

To re-check it: right click your project-->properties-->Android section-->see WHETHER YOUR LIBRARY is **GREEN** . If not, that means you are not correctly included library.

To resolve it, when tried to CREATE LIBRARY FROM EXISTING LIBRARIES, you can check **copy it to your disk**

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should try to clean all zxing library projects, all other referenced libraries and your app project. This helped me with this error message.